PCB routing: how to connect the ground?
I want to create a PCB schematic of a very basic AC/DC converter and I'm a total newbie.


What's the best way to connect ground pins? Transformer is through-hole. Do I have to pour in a second layer and connect pins through vias like on a pic 3?

Or I'm totally wrong?

This is a dangerous circuit. If you are a total newbie, you should absolutely not be making things which directly connect to mains voltage. Particularly as you don't understand the importance of galvanic isolation. (BTW, the output of that circuit is NOT going to be 12VDC.)

It depends on what provides the 300 VAC on left. We can't know that, but if that is a mains plug, you are never allowed to (a) use neutral as ground for other circuits or (b) use earth/ground as return for live if it is ground.

I'm just trying to learn altium and pcb scheme design. I don't mind if the actual numbers or other staff is off (for now at least)

Don't ground your mains side!

I don't know what transformer you're using, but it's nowhere near big enough for even a small mains-frequency transformer. It's probably intended to be used with an offline switching supply.

Topologically all you have to do is run a trace below pin 4 of the transformer and to each pin the rat’s nest indicates- you don’t need the second layer at all. The spacing and trace width will be no worse than elsewhere in your circuit.
This does not mean that the circuit will be safe (it won’t) or useful (can’t see how) but it will match the schematic.
You appear to have come up with a non-standard numbering scheme for the bridge rectifier- though you’ve matched the symbol so the circuit ends up right it’s bad practice and will probably come back to bite you.
